# How to change drawer toggle icon on Android apps?

Tags: android

I have created a drawer toggle on my android app. It is shown on the top-left of the screen. When I click the toggle, a list view items will be shown on the left side. 
Below screen is the home screen:

[image]

when I click the toggle, it will be shown as below:

[image]

Now I want to change the icon of the toggle button by below code:

```
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

The toggle icon is changed to my drawable but the listview items will not be shown when I click the toggle. I wonder why changing the toggle icon disable the toggle click.

Below is my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
//        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v7 `ActionBarDrawerToggle` really only does two things: it opens/closes the drawer, and it provides the hamburger icon and its animation. Calling `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)` will remove its icon, but it also disables the toggle. If you don't want that icon, then you're better off just not using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, and handling opening/closing the drawer yourself.

- First, remove all of your code for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.
- Then set your desired icon with `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator()`.
- In `onOptionsItemSelected()`, if the `MenuItem`'s ID is `android.R.id.home`, open or close the drawer as appropriate.
- Lastly, the `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` functionality of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` can be replaced with a basic `SimpleDrawerListener`.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // *** Set your desired icon
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

        // *** Replace the DrawerListener functionality of the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // *** If the home button is clicked, open/close the drawer as needed
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `syncState()` after changing the icon of the toggle button.

```
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: after add this code the icon can be changed but click on that icon doesn't make the listview item show on the left side. I see Mike responded on my question saying that `ActionBarDrawerToggle` doesn't support changing icon. May be I need a different approach for that

Comment: @ZhaoYi  `ActionBarDrawerToggle` does allow you to change the icon, to a certain extent. However, the icon you set has to be a `DrawerArrowDrawable` subclass, which is probably not what you want. I can post an example of what I suggested in my comment above, if you still need a solution for this.

Comment: @MikeM. A demo code is really helpful. Please post an example if it is not hard for you. Thanks.